# Calculate power of a test - solution verification

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normalization, statistical-power, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ simple random sample from gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(m,4)$. Calculate power of a test ($1-\beta$) for $H_0:m=0$, $H_1:m=2$, when significance level of a test is $\alpha=0.05$ for $n=9\ \&\ n=100$.

**SOLUTION SKETCH:**

From Neyman-Pearson lemma we find $\frac{f_1}{f_0}=\exp{\frac{4}{2\sigma^2}(x-1})$ Thus $x\geq \frac{\sigma^2\ln(c)}{2}+1$ That's right interval of critical region.

Now we look for left one. $\alpha=0.05=\mathbb{P}(\overline{x}>\omega|H_0)=\mathbb{P}(\frac{\overline{x}-0}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}>\frac{\omega-0}{\sigma}\sqrt{n})=\mathbb{P}(U>\frac{\omega}{\sigma}\sqrt{n})$

From tables we get $\omega=\frac{1.645\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

Now we look for $1-\beta$. $\beta=\mathbb{P}(\overline{x}\leq\omega|H_1)=\mathbb{P}(\frac{\overline{x}-2}{\sigma}\sqrt{n}\leq\frac{\omega-2}{\sigma}\sqrt{n})=\mathbb{P}(u\leq1.645-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sigma})$

Since $n=9$ and $\sigma=4$ we have that $\mathbb{P}(u\leq1.645-\frac{\sqrt{9}}{4})=\mathbb{P}(u\leq0.895)$

From the tables we get $\beta\approx0.81 \Rightarrow 1-\beta\approx0.19$

For $n=100$ we have $\beta\approx0.2 \Rightarrow 1-\beta\approx0.8$

Is that right? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). (You will have to delete one of the existing tags.)

Comment: How many [self-study] questions I'm allowed to ask in short period of time? Because I would like to ask about two other similar problems in near future (when I have something that at least looks like a sketch).

Comment: You are welcome to ask as many as you'd like, just as long as you add the tag & follow our policies.